# jsdoc and vscode: Documenting a function passed as an argument to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm trying to document the input parameters to a function in javascript, but I can't work out how to do it in jsdoc.

I've looked at the jsdoc documentation which suggests that using the `@callback` comment is what's required, but Visual Studio Code (vscode) doesn't highlight it as per the screenshot.

The intellisense for the `location` parameter shows that it's type `any` rather than of type `locator` (a function with a parameter of `id` which returns a `Location`).

[image: shows the locater parameter not being type hinted]

Example code which shows a function calling a function passed as a parameter:

```js
class Location {
  constructor(position, count) {
    this.position = position;
    this.count = count;
  }
}

const items = {
  'USB Cable': new Location('Desk Drawer', 123),
  Keyboard: new Location('Desk Surface', 1),
};

/**
 * A locater.
 * @param {string} id 
 * @returns {Location}
 */
const locaterA = id => items[id];

/**
 * Finds the item by its unique id.
 * @callback locater
 * @param {string} id
 * @returns {Location}
 */

/**
 * Attempt to find the item with the given locater.
 * @param {string} id 
 * @param {locater} locater
 */
const locate = (id, locater) => locater(id);

const result = locate('USB Cable', locaterA);

console.log(result);
```

Is this a problem with what I'm doing, vsdoc not supporting the use case, or vscode not supporting it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Edit**: vscode seems to be supporting `@callback` starting from TypeScript **2.9**

Vscode's IntelliSense doesn't support `@callback`. It's being tracked here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7515.

As a convenient workaround you can use [@typedef](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html):

```javascript
/**
 * Finds the item by its unique id.
 * @typedef {function(string): Location} Locater
 */

/**
 * Attempt to find the item with the given locater.
 * @param {string} id 
 * @param {Locater} locater
 */
const locate = (id, locater) => locater(id);
```

[image]

Comment: As a note, if you are not reusing the definition, you dont need @typedef. `* @param {function(string): Location} fn`

Comment: It's worth to mention that the "typedef" is a `regular function` but the variable is an `arrow function` which may be crucial in certain cases.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're using it correctly, per JSDoc itself. However, it looks like Visual Studio may only support a limited subset of JSDoc, which doesn't include `@callback`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt162307.aspx

I don't have Visual Studio handy, but you might try the Google Closure style, which is to do it like this:

```
@param { function(string) : number } locator
```

This says that it's a function that takes a string, and returns a number.

You can find that documentation here: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler (search for "Function Return Type" to jump to the relevant section).

I've noticed with JetBrains stuff at least, that it supports that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Since I was sent here from reddit concerning the documentation of an *async* function passed to another func, I answer here even if it's not exactly the op's question.

It's enough to document the return of the function with a Promise, in ES6 :

```js
/**
 * @param {(input: any) => Promise<any>} asyncFunctionAsParam - async function given
 */
const myfunc = (asyncFunctionAsParam) => {
   // ...
}
```